# Sort a TreeView alphabetically using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, treeview

I'm new to LINQ so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but from what I've started to understand of LINQ makes me believe I should be able to do the following.
I want to take a set of nodes in a TreeView (at any level) and sort them alphabetically related to their siblings.

I *think* I would be able to do the following:

```
//node is already selected
TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
TreeNodeCollection siblingNodes = node.Parent.Nodes;
siblingNodes = siblingNodes.OrderBy(x => x.Text);
```

Since `TreeNodeCollection` implements `IEnumerable`. But the compiler is telling me that

> System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection does not contain a definition
>   for OrderBy and no extension method OrderBy accepting a first argument
>   of type System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(I am using `System.Linq`)

So what am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.100).aspx

System.Linq extension for IEnumerable does not define OrderBy.  It defined OrderBy for IEnumerable<T>.

[EnumerableQuery Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerablequery%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) vs. [EnumerableQuery<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: So is the short of that that I can't do a Linq order on a TreeNodeCollection?

Comment: You cannot directly do a Linq on a TreeNodeCollection.  You can change it to List<TreeNode> or IEnumerable<TreeNode> and then do linq.

Answer (score 3):

Are you missing a reference to LINQ?

```
using System.Linq;
```

**UPDATE:**

You need to define a `TreeViewNodeSorter` in order to be able to sort the nodes. This post will point you in the right direction: [Sorting nodes of a TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618506/sorting-child-nodes-of-a-treeview-after-populating-the-treeview-in-c-sharp-winfo)

Comment: No, I am using System.Linq
(Which was in my original question but another user edited that sentence out...)

Comment: But, that's exactly what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: No, the other extension methods from Linq show up in intellisense, so Linq is there. I can comment out my code and create a dummy array and do a Linq OrderBy operation on that.
It just doesn't like OrderBy in this TreeNodeCollection case.